# How can I add text on meta expr:content?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, seo, blogger, meta

I have a live streaming site, I am having trouble adding text to

```html
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/>
```

I would like to put text before and after the `data:blog.pagename` data tag, so that it will show up in facebook as ( Watch "title of the post" Live Free ).

I am trying something like this below, but it is not working. Please help

```html
<meta expr:content='Watch + data:blog.pageName + Live Free' property='og:title'/>
```

Here is my blogger website URL = https://www.nbalink.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to enclose the text with double quotes (`"`). The following format will work

```html
<meta expr:content='"Watch " + data:blog.pageName + " Live Free"' property='og:title'/>
```

Comment: It works, when I view it on page source. However, it does not work on facebook share, I tried to debug the link on facebook debugger, and still it only catches the data:blog.pageName. Do you have any idea, how to make it work? here the scrape link = https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nbalink.com%2F2019%2F03%2Fdenver-nuggets-vs-washington-wizards.html

Comment: @AlbertoDayao The issue might be happening because of multiple `og:title` tags on the page (Refer to https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxWMW.png). Try removing the extra ones and then scrapping the page again

Comment: @PrayagVermo, I get it now, the problem comes with my template. It has a meta opengraph on it already, however I can't edit it for now because the code are still encrypted. I need to buy the templates first to do that. Thanks for your help. I appreciated it so much. Have a great day. :)